# Jsp how to write html string with response sendredirect

Tags: java, jsp

I need to write a html string which redirects onclick but it is not working, I think it might be because of the double and single quotes but I don't know the correct code.

`String html = "<input type = 'button' value = 'redirect' onclick = 'response.sendRedirect('redirect.jsp')'>";`

Comment: Why are you generating HTML in Java anyway? You can *see* if it’s a problem with quotes by inspecting the page. In any case—if you need to mix quotes you can just escape double-quotes... but this is a path to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using standard Javascript for that?

```
String html = "<input type = 'button' value = 'redirect' onclick = 'document.location.href='redirect.jsp'>";
```